# Renewal of chinese student visa

Tags: china, pakistani-citizen, student-visa

I didn't want to stay for a whole year in China and, for examinations, instead planned to revisit. Now my earlier visa has expired and I have to go back for exams for at most couple of week.

Which visa should I apply for to attend the examinations or is there a way to renew my previous student visa?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said. Get an F Tourist Visa. The documentation required for it won't involve much work on your behave other than preparing as if the visit is a short-term one.

There may be an agency you can contact, such as Sunrise agency in Hong Kong. 
They may be able to advise you on this.

I'm sure there are many people who just need to return for exams.

You can find them here http://www.chinavisa.com.hk/